# LIKE condition in yii

Tags: php, sql, yii, sql-like

1. How to to add like condition in yii?
2. Don't display more than two images in first page.

How can I achieve these things?

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->order = 'id DESC';
    $criteria->condition = 'title LIKE OR description LIKE';


    $item_count = OfferEvents::model()->count($criteria);
    $page_size =5;       

    $pages =new CPagination($item_count);
    $pages->setPageSize($page_size);

    // simulate the effect of LIMIT in a sql query
    $end =($pages->offset+$pages->limit <= $item_count ? $pages->offset+$pages->limit : $item_count);

    $sample =range($pages->offset+1, $end);

    $this->render('index', array(
        'item_count'=>$item_count,
        'page_size'=>$page_size,
        'items_count'=>$item_count,
        'pages'=>$pages,
        'sample'=>$sample,
        ));
}
```

and in my view I add this

```
<div class="page" style="margin-left:500px;">    
        <?php
        $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
        'currentPage'=>$pages->getCurrentPage(),
        'itemCount'=>$item_count,
        'pageSize'=>$page_size,
        'maxButtonCount'=>6,
        'nextPageLabel'=>'Next &gt;',
        'header'=>'',
        ));

        ?>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$criteria->condition = 'title LIKE :title OR description LIKE :description'; // step 1
$criteria->params = array(':title' => $title, ':description' => $description); // step 2
```

Here in

- step 1, Added the two name parameters `:title` and `:description`.
- Then in step 2, Passed values to the `params` method of class `CDbCriteria` Which holds an associative array whose `keys` are parameters in SQL.

**For Pagination:**

```
$page_size = ceil($item_count/2);
```

Comment: it shows me an error unidentified variable title...
and it shows me the same datas in page two also..

Comment: You have to pass both of this `$title` and `$description`